# How to enter safe mode in lg g4c

Tags: lg-g4

I'm trying to boot my LG G4c in safe mode. I've tried 2 methods and none of them works.

1)Turn phone off and then hold power and volume down button until logo appears. Then release them and hold them back again. When I do this, the factory data reset menu appears with just yes an no options and no option for boot in safe mode.

2)Turn phone off and then hold volume down button. Nothing happens.

What is the correct way to enter safe mode ?

(at this point I'd like to add that I want to do this because my phone cannot boot. It only reaches the LG logo screen and the animation keeps playing forever, so I'd like to know if there is a way to do this starting from a switched off phone)

Comment: http://www.hardreset.info/devices/lg/lg-g4c/recovery-mode-and-safe-mode/

Comment: @keshav this is the exact article I read and it doesnt work. I don't want to do a factory reset. Just recovery mode

Comment: Post your edit (last para), my answer is meaningless to your situation but leaving it in case it helps someone else in future

Answer (score 1):

[Safe mode for LG G4C](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid)

> 1. Begin by pressing and holding the Power key unti the phone's options are displayed on the screen.
> 2. Afterwards select and hold Power off until "Restart in safe mode" is displayed.
> 3. Then tap Turn on safe mode in order to confirm the operation.

As far as I know you cannot initate safe mode from phone turned off state.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but phone won't boot so I would like to know if there is a way to do this from power off state and not from inside the operating system.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Can you be a bit more exlicatory?

Answer (score 1):

From how it's described I think you're trying to enter recovery mode, not "safe mode" which is just booting up and disabling all 3rd party apps. In that case, attempt this one: [enter link description here](http://www.androidexplained.com/lg-g4-recovery-mode/)

I have no guarantee this works; after all, even though G4 and G4c are devices of a same generation, their hardware are vastly different. There shouldn't be any harm trying, though.

If even this fails, you might have to resort to download mode to do a full reflash of the phone.

Comment: No I am trying to get to safe mode. I will edit the question to get what I say about recovery mode out because I thought that recovery mode and factory data reset were different menus.